# Apache Bench - how to force PUT, DELETE and POST method

Tags: apache, rest, benchmarking

How to force apache benchmark (ab) app to perform query with REST headers?

Answer (score 7):

From the manual page:

> -i     Do HEAD requests instead of GET.
>
> -p POST-file
>                 File containing data to POST. Remember to also set -T.
>
> -u PUT-file
>                 File containing data to PUT. Remember to also set -T.

But no `DELETE`, et al.

Comment: Thanks. I went through the apache source. It seems that couple of years ago the "-D" option has been discontinued. That's a pity, the TRACE and DELETE options seems to be missing.